# SSIS Execute SQL Task MCH1202 Error

Tags: ssis-2012, db2-400

In an SSIS package I am developing I have an execute SQL task which uses an ODBC Connect to a database on iSeries AS400 the task calls a stored procedure:

```
{CALL DOCTRACK.CORRFEED (?,?,?,? )}
```

The stored procedure takes 4 parameters the first 2 input and last 2 output. 
The Data types of the parameters are char(8), integer, decimal(7,0) and char(80) respectively.  The parameters are mapped to the variables in the package that match the data types.

When I run the package I get the following error message on the Execute SQL Task:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "{CALL DOCTRACK.CORRFEED (?,?,?,? )}" 
>   failed with the following error: "[IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]CEE9901 - 
>   Application error.  MCH1202 unmonitored by CORRFEED at statement 0000000020, instruction X'0000'.". 
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, 
>   parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be causing the error?

Comment: At statement 20 of the stored procedure, an attempt to refer to a BCD data type detected the value is not valid. We do not know the DDL to CREATE PROCEDURE, nor do we know what is stmt/20; not even if the procedure is SQL or EXTERNAL. Given the issue is clearly DB2 for i vs generic DB2, I will change to add the DB2i tag, and DB2400 tag since the system may be ancient per use of the "iSeries AS400" monikers. ref: msg MCH1202 "Decimal data error." "Cause: The sign or the digit codes of the packed or the zoned decimal operand is in error. Valid signs are hex A-F, valid digit range is hex 0-9."

Comment: The stored procedure works fine when run in the iseries with values for the parameters provided.  I have the definition of the stored procedure in front of me.  I am not sure which one is statement 20.  the problem is running from my sisis package created using SqlServer 2012 data tools application.  I tried changing the connection manager to an ADO.NET connection using ODBC Dataprovider.  Still got the same error.  As I recall for ado.net connections I have to change the ?s to named parameters.

Comment: I also do not have the stored procedure in front of me, so clearly I will not *know* what is stmt/20 either. Obviously the problem relates to the data passed for the third parameter marker for the `decimal(7,0)` argument and likely the stmt/20 is effectively `20 CORRFEED.P3 = * (decimal(7,0)*) argv[3];`. So irrespective the ability to CALL with literals\constants, the data from the client is conspicuously problematic. Why not try a local CALL with parameter markers using embedded SQL; if everything could be shared vs kept secret, other easier or better suggestions might be forthcoming.